# drush configuration import export order of the yml

Tags: drush, configuration, importing-exporting

I recently upgraded some minor versions of modules and upgraded Drupal core-recommended to 9.3.3 from 9.2.9. I followed the usual drush updatedb, drush cim -y drush cr and everything looks fine.

In my local env, everything is fine. However, in my dev environment in platform.sh, drush cim keeps importing ALL 860 config files. It doesn't matter how many times you run drush updatedb, drush cim -y and drush cr, it ALWAYS keeps importing the same files.

Running import through the gui yields the same result.

When running drush cim --diff I can see that the yml are the same but in different order, example:

```
    @@ -47,10 +47,10 @@ type_settings:
       weight: 3
     publish:
       label: Publish
-      from:
-        - draft
       to: published
       weight: 1
+      from:
+        - draft
     reject:
       label: Reject
       from:
```

Any ideas are welcome. I will try exporting from the server and importing in local to see if this fixes the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: There was some config ordering introduced in 9.3. Normally when you perform an upgrade locally first you run drush up yes but also in the end you run drush cex. Then deploy. You would have noticed the changes, would have imported them once and done. So simply export your config now, push it and good.

Comment: Thanks leymanxx. 

If I do drush cex from local it does nothing anymore. Is there a way to force the config export in my local? Should I delete all my yaml files and run it again?

Comment: Actually, I deleted all the .yml in config/sync/default , ran drush cex again but now my git repository is identical, meaning, there is nothing to push, config is identical to what it was.

The problem is the drush cim in the server side.

Any tips? I downloaded the config ymls from the server and I was going to run it in my local. Would that work? Thaanks in advance!!

Comment: I Downloaded my configuration from the server and imported it in local. Then did drush cex from local and pushed it to the server. This worked. 

(To be clear, I had done cex the first time, not sure why the order diverged).

Comment: I had a similar issue long time ago https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3103617 . This issue appear from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

I Downloaded my configuration from the server and imported it in local. Then did drush cex from local and pushed it to the server. This solved the issue.

Comment: Same outcome probably if you would have downloaded the live DB and then drush cex.